# Цикл foreach для двух массивов

Tags: массивы, php

Как в одном цикле перебирать два массива по средством `foreach`?
Например `foreach ($this->main as $main)` перебирает один массив.
Но как реализовать, чтобы перебирал два? 
Пробовал такими способами, но не работает:

```
foreach (($this->main as $main) and ($this->adverse as $adverse))
foreach ($this->main as $main, $this->adverse as $adverse)
```

Как можно реализовать?

Заранее благодарю!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял то как-то так...

```
foreach($this->main as $main) {
    foreach($main as $adverse) {
        //...
    }
}
```

Перечитал вопрос и понял что я понял не так :)
В вашем случае лучше всего, склеить 2 массива и выводить все в 1ом цикле...
Даже если и можно както запихивать 2 foreach'a в 1 - так писать не стоит...

Answer (score 2):

*Можно написать что-нибудь в духе:*

```
$arrayObject1 = new ArrayObject($array1);
$arrayObject2 = new ArrayObject($array2);
$iterator1 = $arrayObject1->getIterator();
$iterator2 = $arrayObject2->getIterator();
for ($iterator1->rewind(), $iterator2->rewind();
     $value1 = $iterator1->current(), $value2=$iterator2->current();
     $iterator1->next(), $iterator2->next())
{
    // Здесь уже можно использовать $value1, $value2
}
```

*Или, если* очень часто встречаются такие действия*, то имеет смысл написать функцию-аналог `zip()` в питоне, в котором работает конструкция:

```
for (a, b) in zip(array1, array2):
    # Что-нибудь сделать
```

Answer (score 1):

Если массивы индексные *(а исходя из примера в вопросе ключи массива не используются)*, то достаточно просто одного цикла [for()](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php):

```
$main = array_values($this->main); // получаем индексный массив
$adverse = array_values($this->adverse); // получаем индексный массив
$maxCount = max(count($main), count($adverse));
for($i=0; $i < $maxCount; $i++) {
    if(isset($main[$i])) {
       // попадаем под условие, если элемент в массиве $main есть
       // значение в $main[$i]
    }
    if(isset($adverse[$i])) {
       // попадаем под условие, если элемент в массиве $adverse есть
       // значение в $adverse[$i]
    }
}
unset($main);
unset($adverse);
```

В данном случае время работы алгоритма линейно, быстрее вложенных циклов и равно (n), где n максимальное кол-во элементов во всех массивах.