# Цикл для двух массивов

Tags: массивы, php, циклы

Доброе время суток, нашел тему [Цикл foreach для двух массивов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/43399/php-%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB-foreach-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%85-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2) но не совсем понятно как работает этот цикл

```
$arrayObject1 = new ArrayObject($array1);
$arrayObject2 = new ArrayObject($array2);
$iterator1 = $arrayObject1->getIterator();
$iterator2 = $arrayObject2->getIterator();
for ($iterator1->rewind(), $iterator2->rewind();
     $value1 = $iterator1->current(), $value2=$iterator2->current();
     $iterator1->next(), $iterator2->next())
{
    // Здесь уже можно использовать $value1, $value2
}
```

Как вытащить ключ tk в верхнем примере, Например если в foreach

```
$data[$ser_row[$groop]]['tk'][] = $ser_row['servicename'];
    foreach($data as $keydata => $serdata) {
    $tk = $serdata['tk']; 
    }
```

Comment: Выполните: echo("<pre>".print_r($data)."</pre>")
и поделитесь результатом. Никак не могу представить себе структуру массива, что Вы создали...

Comment: Array ( [name] => Array ( [data] => Array ( [0] => 2013-08-04 ) [id] => Array ( [0] => 45911 ) [tk] => Array ( [0] => TS2 ) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для массива

```
Array
(
    [name] => Array
        (
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2013-08-04
                )

            [id] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2013-08-04
                )

            [tk] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2013-08-04
                )

        )

)
```

---

```
$arrayObject1 = new ArrayObject($data);
$iterator1 = $arrayObject1->getIterator(); //Получаем итератор
for ($iterator1->rewind(); //Вернуться в начало массива
     $value1 = $iterator1->current(); //Получить значение текущей ячейки массива и присвоить его переменной $value1
     $iterator1->next()) //Перейти к след. элементу массива
{

    if($value1["tk"]!==NULL)
    {   
        $tk = $value1["tk"]; //Переменная "$tk" получит значение "Array( [0] => 2013-08-04 )"
    }
} /*Цикл выполниться только один раз, так как непосредственно в $data содержится 
только одна пара "ключ-значение": [name] => Array (...) */
```